# Div dropdowns interfering with eachother

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to create a bit of a portal page but I'm having an issue with these dropdown buttons. I'd like if all of the dropdowns could be on screen at once but I'm not sure how I could do that without having the dropdowns with eachother. Here's the fiddle for what I'm working with.
http://jsfiddle.net/Propulsionz/37ub1ge7/

Here's the HTML

```
        <div class="fadeIn" id="logo"><span class="dark">MC</span><span class="light">Market</span></div>
    <div id="action"><span class="dark">What would you like to do?</span></div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('buyselltoggle');"><div id="button"><div id="text"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><br>Buy/Sell</div></div></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('offertoggle');"><div id="button"><div id="text"><i class="fa fa-share"></i><br>Offer</div></div></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('hiretoggle');"><div id="button"><div id="text"><i class="fa fa-users"></i><br>Hire</div></div></a>
    </div>
    <div id="buyselltoggle">
        <a href="#"><div id="button2"><div id="text2">Buy/Sell</div></div></a><br>
        <a href="#"><div id="button2"><div id="text2">Buy/Sell</div></div></a><br>
        <a href="#"><div id="button2"><div id="text2">Buy/Sell</div></div></a><br>
        <a href="#"><div id="button2"><div id="text2">Buy/Sell</div></div></a><br>
        <a href="#"><div id="button2"><div id="text2">Buy/Sell</div></div></a>
    </div>
    <div id="offertoggle">
        <a href="#"><div id="button2"><div id="text2">Buy/Sell</div></div></a><br>
        <a href="#"><div id="button2"><div id="text2">Buy/Sell</div></div></a><br>
        <a href="#"><div id="button2"><div id="text2">Buy/Sell</div></div></a><br>
        <a href="#"><div id="button2"><div id="text2">Buy/Sell</div></div></a><br>
        <a href="#"><div id="button2"><div id="text2">Buy/Sell</div></div></a>
    </div>
    <div id="hiretoggle">
        <a href="#"><div id="button2"><div id="text2">Buy/Sell</div></div></a><br>
        <a href="#"><div id="button2"><div id="text2">Buy/Sell</div></div></a><br>
        <a href="#"><div id="button2"><div id="text2">Buy/Sell</div></div></a><br>
        <a href="#"><div id="button2"><div id="text2">Buy/Sell</div></div></a><br>
        <a href="#"><div id="button2"><div id="text2">Buy/Sell</div></div></a>
    </div>
    </center>
    <div id="bar"><a href="#"><div id="continue">Click to continue to the forums>></div></a></div>
    <script>
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'table')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'table';
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you mean by all the dropdowns at the same time? Do you want to have 15 buttons below the three boxes? Or just five buttons when the large one is clicked?

Comment: A list of five small buttons that are shown when a large button is clicked. The current problem is that when clicking more than one large button the second list of five small buttons will go out of place. When there is only one list toggled it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have many ID's that are not unique.

> The ID must be unique in a document, and is often used to retrieve the
>   element using

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.id

This will affect your JavaScript. I would recommend using classes instead if you want non-unique identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Is this closer to what you want (toggle on click)?

We can spiff it up a bit.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/fmv13r67/)

JS

```
$('.buysellbutton').on('click', function(){
      $('#buyselltoggle').toggle();
});
$('.offerbutton').on('click', function(){
      $('#offertoggle').toggle();
});
$('.hirebutton').on('click', function(){
      $('#hiretoggle').toggle();
});
$(':not(#wrapper)').on('click', function(){
});
```